# VirtualBox VM changes MAC address after imported to Oracle Cloud Infrastructure

Tags: virtualbox, mac-address, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I should start by saying that I am a novice in OCI and VirtualBox.

My goal is to create a VirtualBox VM and give it a certain MAC address and run it in OCI with the same MAC address.

Currently when I start the imported VM in OCI it has a different MAC. Is there a way to keep the MAC address ? Additionally, is there a way to edit the MAC address to OCI instance?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. MAC addresses are assigned by Oracle Cloud's networking service and cannot be changed.

[Source](https://www.oracle.com/cloud/networking/virtual-cloud-network-faq.html).